# How do I pass useState from one component to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to make a login modal that changes to the signup modal when the signup button is clicked within the Login.js. Currently, I have a header with a login button. When the login button is clicked, the current state is displayed (default value is ). I would like the signup button within Login.js to be able to update the state in order for that modal to .

Header.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Login from "../modals/Login";
import Signup from "../modals/Signup";

export default function Header() {

    const [lmodal, setModal] = useState(<Login />);

    return (
...
    {lmodal}
...
)
}
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Signup from "../modals/Signup";

export default function Login() {

return (
...
**// Clicking the button should change the state from Header.js to <Signup />**
 <button onClick={() => { setModal(<Signup />) }} className="btn btn-primary">Signup</button>
...
)
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

States and components are different in concept.
What you coould possible do to reach the wanted behavior is to use the state to toogle the component, for exemple:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Login from "../modals/Login";
import Signup from "../modals/Signup";

export default function Header() {

    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

    return (
...
    {modal && <Login />}
    <Signup modal={modal} setModal={setModal}/>
...
)}
```

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Signup from "../modals/Signup";

export default function Login({modal, setModal}) {

return (
...
 <button onClick={() => setModal(true)} className="btn btn-primary">Signup</button>
...
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't setModal from within the Login component because setModal is in the Header component.